# Typesafe Activator Behind Corporate Proxy Fails

Tags: windows, scala, proxy, typesafe-activator

I'm trying to use Typesafe Activator behind a corporate proxy using CNTLM on Windows. I've set up the appropriate configs in ~.activator\activatorconfig.txt.

I know I've set it up correctly as I can see activator and the proxy talk to each other and I can see activator succeed in downloading lots of jars. For some reason though it fails at `junit 4.5` and `com.typesafe.akka#akka-testkit_2.11;2.3.3`. Meanwhile, sbt succeeds in downloading everything it needs.

The same happens if I try on other machines. This happens with jdk 7. With jdk 8 it fails to download anything.

Has anyone seen this before or had a similar experience?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would you mind trying these snapshots which have proxy-related bug fixes?

Full download: http://downloads.typesafe.com/typesafe-activator/1.0-4ec078b5d5c58b4a023765c22914ef49a544f21b/typesafe-activator-1.0-4ec078b5d5c58b4a023765c22914ef49a544f21b.zip
Mini (no offline): http://downloads.typesafe.com/typesafe-activator/1.0-4ec078b5d5c58b4a023765c22914ef49a544f21b/typesafe-activator-1.0-4ec078b5d5c58b4a023765c22914ef49a544f21b-minimal.zip

Also, be sure to set https.proxyHost etc in addition to http.proxyHost etc

Thanks!

Comment: YESSS!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! It worked!!! thank you so much, was really banging my head against the wall on this one :)